# Why were most of the Arab spring revolutions followed by civil wars?

Tags: civil-war, revolutions

Why were most of the Arab spring revolutions followed by civil wars?

Why did the US and EU either sell weapons or give military support to the warring parties?

Comment: Not all. See Tunisia.  A pluralistic republican democracy

Comment: @JamesK yes i know , but Tunisia has almost broken into a civil war in 2011-2012

Comment: @JamesK and now Tunisia have a political instability and an economic crisis

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Perhaps not directly, but there have been reports of European countries selling weapons to countries that are known to then sell them to Syria. For example: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jul/27/weapons-flowing-eastern-europe-middle-east-revealed-arms-trade-syria

Comment: While Egypt had lots of civil unrest in the past 10 years including civil casualties in the hundreds and the Sinai insurgency still ongoing, I wouldn't really call the situation in Egypt a "civil war" on the same level as what happens in Libya or Syria.

Comment: Re _"...giving **them** military support"_: civil wars have at least two sides.  Please specify which side or sides the pronoun *"them"* refers to.

Comment: Because most revolutions are followed by civil wars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Foreign meddling** (especially USA/CIA and NATO).

The uprisings which didn't end up in civil war originated from genuine causes.

BTW, all of the chaos in the Middle East and North Africa could be explained by US/Israeli/Saudi versus Iranian/Russian interest in the region.

Take for example [**Syria**](https://www.quora.com/Would-Turkey-invade-Idlib-a-province-in-Syria/answers/201100026)

> Initially, Syria was divided between
>
> 1. Kurds backed by the USA
> 2. Bashar al Asad backed by Russia + Iran
> 3. Syrian rebels backed by Turkey
>
> Here were their objectives:
>
> 1. USA’s objective was to [oust Bashar al Asad](https://www.mintpressnews.com/declassified-cia-report-exposes-25-years-u-s-plans-destabilize-syria/225553/) to eliminate [Syrian (+Iranian) threat against Israel](https://www.cufi.org/how-seriously-should-israel-take-syrias-golan-heights-threat/) ([also](https://www.timesofisrael.com/us-warns-syrian-regime-not-to-advance-toward-israeli-border))
> 2. Russia’s objective was [to establish a Russian military base in Syria](https://www.the-american-interest.com/2020/01/02/russian-land-power-in-the-mediterranean) by keeping Bashar in power
> 3. Turkish objective was [to eliminate Kurdish separatists](https://www.politico.eu/article/8-questions-about-turkeys-incursion-into-syria-answered/), and also resolve the Syrian refugee crisis in Turkey by creating a 30km wide
>      Safe Zone along the Turkish border so that refugees can return to
>      Syria. As a relief, Turkey will provide them with food, healthcare,
>      education, and so on.
>
> Later, the equation changed when Turkey eliminated Kurds and cornered
>   Bashar’s military.
>
> 1. The USA [abandoned its primary objective](https://www.euractiv.com/section/global-europe/news/us-accepts-assad-staying-in-power-but-wont-give-aid) and resorted to supporting Turkey
> 2. Russia continued to support Bashar’s force but trying to make them abide by the trilateral agreement made by Russia, Iran, and Turkey. Also, they saved Bashar's force by bombing Turkish positions.
> 3. Turkey is [bombing both Bashar’s forces](https://www.france24.com/en/20200227-erdogan-calls-emergency-meeting-after-deadly-attack-on-turkish-troops-in-syria) and [Iran-backed Hezbollah](https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/international/middle-east/1582973306-several-hezbollah-members-killed-in-turkish-strike-in-syria-reports) as they are opposing the Turkish plan.

The same kind of explanation could be given for **Lybia** and **Iraq**.

Comment: Can you develop more or give me some sources ?.

Comment: for exemple what is the source of this 'USA’s objective was to oust Bashar al Asad to eliminate Syrian threat against Israel'

Comment: @Taher, enough evidence added.

Comment: What a tangled web they weave.